# How to find out which rows are missing in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I work for a company that does business with phone companies and has thousands of lines. This is a sample of the document. Only with about 4 thousand rows.

I need a formula that tells me what columns are empty/blank in each row.

[image]

What I want is to do is say in call L2, columns H, I, J, and K are missing/blank. I would like to do this without VBA also but if it is impossible, I will accept the vba code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for columns **H,I,J,K** in **L1** enter:

```
=IF(H1="","H","") & IF(I1="","I","") & IF(J1="","J","") & IF(K1="","K","")
```

and copy down:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To put a space between the letters, use this formula instead:

```
=IF(H1="","H ","") & IF(I1="","I ","") & IF(J1="","J ","") & IF(K1="","K","")
```

Comment: This is what they asked for. It might be wise to possibkly wrap each cell value with Trim() if these are data entries +1

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. Further question. How do I put space in between the letters?

Comment: Thank you. I made an error earlier. Both rows I and J will either be empty or one will be empty. They will never both be empty. How do I replace that with an "OR".

If I is filled in, J will never be occupies and vice versa. Can I make the code ignore one row if the other is occupied?
Thanks a lot!!